# Could not load file or assembly 'Intel.Misc.Utilities'

Tags: visual-studio-2015, intel

After uninstalling Visual Studio 2017 and Intel Composer 2016 I get the following error in Visual Studio 2015 when compiling a project or basically anything else:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Intel.Misc.Utilities, Version=16.0.14.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=f4875dd4c8d7762f' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

A complete reinstall of both Visual Studio 2015 and Intel Composer 2018 did not solve it.

Also fixing the Visual Studio 2015 via the setup does not work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found one work around, but it is not pretty, it is simply reinstalling Intel compiler 2016 and then everything worked again. Hope in future somebody has a better answer.